# inserting a record to elasticsearch using Springboot Restful service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

can any please guide on how to insert record to elastic search using spring boot rest service

we are using spring boot,restful service.

I have  tried with elastic document but couldnt get much from it

Have used the below approach but index is not getting created in ES

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("INDEX_NAME", "type", "id")


                .source(jsonMap)

                .opType(DocWriteRequest.OpType.CREATE);

        try {

            ActionFuture<IndexResponse> response = client.index(indexRequest);
```

Comment: I am updating index when I do CRUD operation with database something similar to this... https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/

Comment: Thanks Yogen for the response ,above approach is not working with Elastic 6 and above version